# Can a pilot in a small spaceship feel G force in space?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, inertial-frames, centrifugal-force

I am not really good in physics so I might be wrong at some points, but here is the situation. Consider a spaceship of the size of a fighter plane. And like a fighter plane, the ship is very mobile. The interior is pressurised.

Would the pilot feel g-forces when accelerating and decelerating the ship? If he does, could that force be enough to make him faint  at some point as  pilots of fighter planes sometimes  do?

Comment: Yep! That's how it works.

Comment: The only question is... why would you think otherwise?

Comment: Like I said, I am not good in physics so I though that maybe things were different in space because of gravity or other factors. Obviously I was wrong.

Comment: What you call "G-force" is nothing but just plain force.  Q: When the pilot hits the throttle, why doesn't the ship zoom away and leave him behind?  A: because the ship _pushes_ him (i.e., it applies a _force_ to his back-side.)  "G-force" is what it feels like to be accelerated.  Q:  If you sit on the ground, why don't you sink into the center of the Earth?  A: Because the ground _pushes_ you upward (i.e., it applies a force to your bottom.)  The feeling of being supported by the ground is exactly the same as the feeling of being accelerated at 1G.  In fact, it _is_ acceleration at 1G.

Comment: @CuriousOne - that is not really a helpful comment.

Comment: @Peter4075: I find it very helpful to analyze cases of failing physics intuition. It's a wonderful way to learn about physics and to hone said intuition for the future.

Comment: @CuriousOne - Honing "physics intuition" needn't involve flip, superior comments. Not the best way to encourage learners to use this site.

Comment: @Peter4075: Curiously I can actually think of a number of good reasons why the OP and all but approx. the last ten generations of mankind thought otherwise including such great thinkers as Aristotle and Ptolemy... part of the "growing up" process in physics is to let go of naively "obvious" but completely false concepts like absolute space and time. A lot of that is actually the fun part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a good knowledge of physics but the basic answer is yes, g-force is pretty much an acceleration force.

For example 1g (Earth gravity) is basically an acceleration of 9.8m/s2 towards the Earth, you don't accelerate because the ground resists this force.

In terms of whether some one could pass out then yes you could. In space the weightlessness actually comes from a lack of acceleration, however the speed can still be very high (needs to be if you want to stay in orbit!).

Answer (score 1):

The g-force experienced by the pilot's spaceship is no different from that of of the pilot of a fighter plane (on Earth) or a racing car driver (on Earth) with exception of (perhaps) magnitude.

The pilot will experience three types of g-forces:

1. **During linear accelerations:**

The pilot will experience an inertial force opposite to the sense of acceleration of:

$F=ma$, where the ratio $\frac{a}{g}$ is the number of g the pilot will experience.

2. **During linear decelerations ('braking'):**

The pilot will experience an inertial force opposite to the sense of deceleration of:

$F=ma$, where the ratio $\frac{a}{g}$ is the number of g the pilot will experience.

3. **While changing direction ('steering'):**

For example [during a banked turn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force#Example:_The_banked_turn) the pilot will experience a centripetal force $F_c=ma_c$ pointing away from the centre of the turn, where $a_c=\frac{v^2}{r}$ ($v$ is speed, and $r$ the radius of the turn).

The ratio $\frac{a_c}{g}$ is the number of g the pilot will experience.

Comment: Would that difference of magnitude would be enough to make a difference from earth?

Comment: @Redleouf: It really is about 'from Earth', 'on Earth' or 'difference from Earth'. The experienced g forces depend only on the accelerations. Very fast racing drivers hurtling around a track may experience higher g forces than sedate space ship pilots. The Newton's Laws of Motion apply everywhere, thus flying to the Moon is no different from driving round a track: only the actual accelerations/decelerations/changes in direction determine what g forces are at play.